# Usage of StringTemplate

Tags: string-manipulation

The documentation for StringTemplate has the following example

```
In[1]:= StringTemplate[
  "The first `1` Fibonnaci numbers are: <* Table[Fibonacci[n+1],{n,#1}] // Row *>."][5]

Out[1]= "The first 5 Fibonnaci numbers are: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8."
```

However, when used in Mathematica, we get the following output

```
In[31]:= StringTemplate[
  "The first `1` Fibonnaci numbers are: <* Table[Fibonacci[n+1],{n,#1}] // Row *>."][5]

Out[31]= "The first 5 Fibonnaci numbers are: 12358."
```

How can one get the output with the commas between the numbers (i.e., like 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation example is clearly wrong. Probably was written without proper testing. A second argument giving a spacer element must be added to `Row`. The quotes delimiting the spacer string must be escaped.

```
StringTemplate[
  "The first `1` Fibonnaci numbers are: <* \
     Row[Table[Fibonacci[n+1],{n, #1}],\", \"] *>."][5]
```

> ```
> "The first 5 Fibonnaci numbers are: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8."
> ```

Answer (score 5):

I would say that there may be a mistake in the documentation. In order to get the comma separated format, you should provide an [explicit separator to `Row`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html):

```
StringTemplate["The first `1` Fibonacci numbers are: <* Row[Table[Fibonacci[n + 1], {n, #1}], \", \"] *>."][5]
```